# New embedded project; which ARM CPU has best Linux support?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, embedded-linux

We are planning a new embedded board that must run custom Linux software we've developed.  Our current platform uses the 2.6.32 kernel, Debian Lenny on an x86.  We do not have any custom hardware and all interfacing at the moment is via serial ports.  I've been looking TI AM355x chip, but it doesn't look like they have their Linux SDK ready yet.  There is also the BeagleBone, but that appears to not have any official TI support, the earliest kernel is 3.0 and they are running Debian Wheezy.

Can anyone recommend a well supported ARM CPU that can run the 2.6.32 kernel with Debian Lenny?  By well supported I would want something that is supported in the mainline kernel, is backed by a company with good commitment and history of Linux support, and has paid support options.

I know this is a bit general but hopefully someone can respond with vendors to look at & vendors to definitely avoid?

TY,
Fred

Comment: I've run Ubuntu on PandaBoards http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandaboard, based on Cortex A9 chip

Comment: Good suggestion, isn't TI going to phase out the OMAP however?  Concerned about long-term support.  How good was the driver support?  Everything work OK, any gotchas?

Comment: I am quite confident TI and community will support it for at least next 3 years. Would it be enough for you?

Comment: Probably, I need to find out more what our needs are.

Comment: Pandaboard is only available for evaluation purposes and in small quantities. It is not intended, nor particularly suitable for any kind of production use.

Comment: Are you saying you are making the board, or that you want an off-the-shelf board you can just use as-is as your hardware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are putting the cart before the horse here.   I would recommend choosing the platform first and then worry about the operating system afterwards.  Be aware even with the same kernel and user-space versions from the same vendors, there are significant differences between x86 and ARM systems - particularly in terms of power management and drivers.

Kernel version  2.6.32 is also pretty old - in fact ancient in the fast moving world of ARM SoC.  New functionality tends not to be backported.

In terms of *best supported* ARM SoCs at least the following are factors:

- A particular kernel tree (almost never main-line) supports all of the functionality of the ARM SoC
- [Paid for] Commercial or vendor support is available for the SoC
- Wide choice of COTS systems available using SoC.
- Full system support in OS distributions
- Supported by developer/enthusiast community

Taking [Pandaboard](http://www.pandaboard.org) as a case study since it's been mentioned by several other posters:

- Most device functionality is supported in recent mainline distros
- Wide community support - although very little of the documentation is authoritative or maintained and answers can be hard to find.  You'll be on your own if you get stuck.
- You can't buy Pandaboard for production use, it's sold as a evaluation board with little vendor support.
- You can't buy Pandaboard in volume.
- TI don't provide support for OMAP4 unless you're a tier 1 OEM, although most of the datasheet (7k pages, 44MiB) is public.  Other parts under NDA.

It's fairly clear from your description that this doesn't fit your needs. I would therefore suggest looking at COTS systems.

I've had good experience using products from [PhyTec](http://www.phytec.eu/europe), who make a number of different ARM SoC-based systems (in some cases, on interchangeable modules).  They ship their systems qualified with [Pengutronix's](http://www.pengutronix.de/index_de.html) Linux Distro, although there's nothing to stop you using their kernel and somebody else's user-space  (I used Angstrom).  PhyTec's kernel patches are contributed to the [linux-omap](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/tmlind/linux-omap.git;a=summary) tree.  [5]

There are plenty of other vendors of similar COTS systems.

Needless to say, these COTS board are not directly supported by mainline distros, although in practice are fairly close.

[5]: Linux mainline is worth avoiding for ARM SoC.

Comment: Similar to phytec solutions, you can get modules with the Nvidia Tegra chips form [Toradex](http://www.toradex.com). Many of the adjustments for the Tegra chips are already in the mainline. Support Linux is directly provided by Toradex.

Comment: "Linux mainline is worth avoiding for ARM SoC" I wonder on what grounds you are making such claims? Interestingly, I would make the opposite suggestion: "*vendor* kernel is worth avoiding" since their support is usually horrible, and sticking to mainline is what results in the more robust path since at least I have community support that way (disclaimer: I am a kernel developer myself).

Comment: In any case, I've upvoted this reply. It sounds like you will need an SOM with commercial suppport. There are plenty of companies offering that. This list might be useful http://elinux.org/Computer-on-Module, or try googling for "Linux SOM".

Answer (score 2):

try [cubieboard](http://cubieboard.org), it is yet another more high-end raspberrypi.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Rasberry Pi and PandaBoard would suit you perfectly.

First one has Debian Wheezy working on (http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads), second one - Ubuntu (http://omappedia.org/wiki/PandaBoard_Ubuntu_How-tos)

Comment: Yes that is a good suggestion.  Did the support for the Broadcom chip make it into the main kernel?  Any ideas what the long term plan for Linux support by Broadcom is?  I am wary of product support disappearing, but the Pi is quite popular yes.

Comment: Do you know what kernel version that patch is for?  We use the older 2.6 kernel so moving to a newer 3.x kernel would be a bit of a risk for us.  We have lots of proven software; prefer to make as few changes as possible

Comment: So what are your main goals - find better board and keep kernel and keep using the same kernel you made a lot of modifications for?

Comment: Project is still early phase so still working out the goals.  I believe the goals are to find cheaper solution that our existing x86 system, with very good Linux support (paid priority support option), that can run the same kernel & Debian release we're using now.  We have a large body of existing software and making any change (OS version, kernel version) will require a full QA cycle that is quite time consuming.

Comment: You're not about to avoid a QA cycle by sticking with the same release of Debian running on the same platform unless all of your code is interpreted.

Comment: If you move from x86 to another processor e.g. ARM, that is a change IMO that makes the QA cycle appropriate.

Comment: how much board do you need to buy?

Answer (score 0):

Wandboard is for me no1 contender by far-> [LINK](http://www.wandboard.org/index.php/details)

GPIO...single, double or quad core....giga lan...you name it!